# How to mimic an HTML element and add attributes to it in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, element

I have a method called handle_value_tag_click(value) which takes an HTML element (value) as a parameter.

I want to call this function from another function, but this time I don't have a 'ready made' HTML element ... in the initial situation I pass a `this` element and the function unwraps the parameters appropriately.

My guess is I have to construct the element by using a JS object. This is my attempt:

```
    var value = new Object();
        value.attr("valueType","NumericQueryValue");
        value.attr("lower",lowerBound);
        value.attr("upper",upperBound);
    handle_value_tag_click(value);
```

However I get the error `value.attr is not a function`, how can I solve this error, or get the appropriate behavour (passing parameters to the handle_value_tag_click() function) in some other way.

Answer (score 5):

what if you say this?:

```
var value = $("<div />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an element like this:

```
var value = $(document.createElement("div"));
```

It won't be in the DOM but every jQuery method will work on it.

Comment: thanks my guess is it would work, but I'll go with valipour's method since it's so simple.

Comment: actually they're almost the same, except mine is faster :) you can check it here: http://jsperf.com/createelement1